# How to remove a Wine prefix from change prefix list

Tags: linux, wine

So I've been trying to install an app on Wine, and I accidentally created a new prefix.  It shows in the Change Prefix menu, and I just want to get rid of it.  However, when I click the - button, it doesn't get removed from the list... it just stays there!  Is there some kind of hidden file that is there?  I just want it to go away...

Answer (score 2):

I know that this answer is a little late but answering it for anyone else landing on this page might be useful. Since a WINE prefix is a folder that contains all sorts of configurations, deleting it fixed my issue. The default WINE prefix is ~/.wine, so by issuing the command 'rm -r ~/.wine' it will be removed. When using a different prefix, it should be possible to replace the default prefix in this command with the desired prefix.

Comment: Why would you delete ~/.wine and everything in it when the problem is a different prefix?

Comment: When using a different prefix, it should be possible to replace the default prefix in this command with the desired prefix.